# Google Sheet query where literal string contains field value

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, match, substitution, google-query-language

Let's say you have a table of properties in a Google Sheet...

| Col A (Name) |
| --- |
| Property 1 |
| Property 2 |
| Property 3 |
| Property 4 |
| Property 5 |

... and you want a formula-driven solution that pulls data on certain properties, specified by a comma-separated literal string like "Property 2,Property 5".

The query() function comes to mind, which uses mySQL syntax. I tried these WHERE queries:

- SELECT A WHERE 'Property 2, Property 5' LIKE '%{$A}%'  -- No error but returns empty set.
- SELECT A WHERE INSTR('Property 2, Property 5', A) -- returned error: Unable to parse query string for function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " 'INSTR'" at line 1, column 16.  Was expecting one of: "("... "("...

Is there some other query to find the needle in the haystack, where the haystack is a literal string and the needle is a field in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "select A where A matches 'Property 2|Property 5'"; )
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I knew there had to be some way, and =substitute() can replace the commas with pipes.  Thanks!